# how to plot graded letters like A* in matplotlib

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

i'm a complete beginner and i have a college stats project, im comparing **exam scores** for our year group and the one below. i collected my own data and since i do cs i decided to try visualize the data with pandas and matplotlib (my first time). i was able to read the csv file into a dataframe with columns = Level,Grade,Difficulty,Happy,MAG. **Level** is just ' year group ' e.g. AS or A2. and **MAG** is like a minimum expected grade, the rest are numeric values out of 5.

i want to do some type of plotting but i cant' seem to get it work.
**i want to plot** revision against difficulty? **for AS group** and try show a correlation. i also want to show a barchart ( if appropriate ) for Grade Vs MAG.

here is the csv https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/169UKfcet1qh8ld-eI7B4U14HIl7pvgZfQLE45NrleX8/edit?usp=sharing

this is the code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('Report Task.csv')
df.columns = ['Level','Grade','Difficulty','Revision','Happy','MAG'] #numerical values are out of 5
df[df.Level.str.match('AS')] #to get only AS group
plt.plot(df.Revision, df.Difficulty)
```

this is my first time ever posting on stack so im really sorry if i did something wrong.

Comment: `df[df.Level.str.match('AS')]` does not change your data. Maybe you want `df=df[df.Level.str.match('AS')]`

Comment: Or `df[df.Level.str.match('AS')].plot(x='Revision', y='Difficulty')`.

Comment: @QuangHoang i tried that but the plot looks really bad, as shown here https://ibb.co/JcgXp9k
it doesn't have to be a PLOT but just anything that would work at this point...

Comment: The graph being bad is unrelated to how to plot it...

Comment: oh, could that just be because of my data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For difficulty vs revision, you were using a line plot. You're probably looking for a scatter plot:

```py
df = df[df.Level.str.match('AS')] # note the extra `df =` as per comments
plt.scatter(x=df.Revision, y=df.Difficulty)
plt.xlabel('Revision')
plt.ylabel('Difficulty')
```

Alternatively you can plot via pandas directly:

```py
df = df[df.Level.str.match('AS')] # note the extra `df =` as per comments
df.plot.scatter(x='Revision', y='Difficulty')
```

[image: difficulty vs revision]

Comment: ohh okay thanks, i think my data is just bad and thats why the plots and scatters look bad